# Git folder added to branch shows up in master after branch commit

Tags: git, branch

I've got some strange behavior in git where I create a branch. Copy a folder over add the folder and commit the changes to the branch. I then checkout master and the folder is listed there although it is untracked at this point.. This isn't necessarily a problem because I can delete untracked files.

Has anyone else run into this?

Create empty repo add file and commit

```
[bash]# git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /usr/src/config/.git/
[bash]# echo 'test' > test
[bash]# git add test
[bash]# git commit -m 'Initial Commit'
[master (root-commit) 76fcfe1] Initial Commit
 Committer: hmmhesays
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com

If the identity used for this commit is wrong, you can fix it with:

    git commit --amend --author='Your Name <you@example.com>'

 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 test
[bash]# ls -lah
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Mar 13 15:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4.0K Mar 13 15:56 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4.0K Mar 13 15:57 .git
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    5 Mar 13 15:57 test
```

Create and and checkout branch

```
[bash]# git branch test_branch
[bash]# git checkout test_branch
Switched to branch 'test_branch'
[bash]# ls -lah
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Mar 13 15:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4.0K Mar 13 15:56 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4.0K Mar 13 15:57 .git
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    5 Mar 13 15:57 test
[bash]# git branch
  master
* test_branch
```

Copy folder. Add and commit.

```
[bash]# cp -a /etc etc
[bash]# git add etc
[bash]# git commit -m 'branch commit'
[test_branch 49ff84f] branch commit
 Committer: hmmhesays
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com

If the identity used for this commit is wrong, you can fix it with:

    git commit --amend --author='Your Name <you@example.com>'

 957 files changed, 108376 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 etc/.pwd.lock
/* Truncated output */
 create mode 100644 etc/yum/version-groups.conf
[bash]# ls -lah
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Mar 13 15:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4.0K Mar 13 15:56 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4.0K Mar 13 15:58 .git
drwxr-xr-x 71 root root 4.0K Mar  2 13:16 etc
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    5 Mar 13 15:57 test
```

Checkout master and folder from branch is there

```
[bash]# git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
[bash]# ls -lah
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Mar 13 15:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4.0K Mar 13 15:56 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4.0K Mar 13 15:58 .git
drwxr-xr-x 31 root root 4.0K Mar 13 15:58 etc <-- Directory shows up in master after branch commit even though it is untracked.
rw-r--r--  1 root root    5 Mar 13 15:57 test
[bash]# git ls-files
test 
[bash]#
```

Comment: Are all files still there in the etc directory after switch to master? Does "git config core.excludesfile" print out anything?

Comment: git config core.excludesfile results in no output. Looking at this further it seems in the master branch only the ~/etc directory structure is there. No files from the test_branch are there.